# Interface To Generic Casting issue

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, interface

I'm implementing a custom data store against an in memory state tree and I'm running into some issues with my indexing.  My indexes are meant to be covering, so they should return the object not just a position. An index has a name, and a List of objects.  Those objects can be different underlying types so the indexed objects are `IHasUUID` which indicates an item has a UUID.

```
public class DataIndex
{
    public string Name;
    public IDictionary<string, List<IHasUUID>> Index;
}

public class Indexer
{

    private List<DataIndex> Indexes;
...
    public List<IHasUUID> GetIndexedItems(List<IHasUUID> indexBy) 
    {
        var indexer = GetIndexByKeys<IHasUUID>(indexBy);
        var indexHash = GetHashKey(indexBy);

        return GetIndexValues<IHasUUID>(indexer, indexHash);
    }

    private List<T> GetIndexValues<T>(DataIndex indexBy, string indexHash) where T : IHasUUID
    {
        if (indexBy == null)
            return new List<T>();

        return ((IList<T>)indexBy.Index[indexHash]).ToList();
    }

}
```

I generate the key to the dictionary using a reflection method where I look at the things being used as the index key and append the type string names

So I ask my Engine to FindRecords, no problem

```
public List<T> FindRecords<T>(IHasUUID indexBy) where T : IHasUUID
{
   var indexedIds = Indexer.GetIndexedItems(new List<IHasUUID>() { indexBy });

   return ((IList<T>)indexedIds).ToList();
}
```

Here I run into a wall on the FindRecords return

I have

```
return ((IList<T>)indexedIds).ToList();
```

and I tried

```
return indexedIds.ToList();
```

Neither one is able to cast up to T.  Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

*EDIT*

I do seem to be much closer,

```
    public class DataIndex
    {
        public DataIndex()
        {
            Index = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<IHasUUID>>();
        }

        public string Name;
        public Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<IHasUUID>> Index;
    }

    public class Indexer
    {

        private List<DataIndex> Indexes;

        public Indexer()
        {
            Indexes = new List<DataIndex>();
        }
        public IEnumerable<T> GetIndexedItems<T>(IEnumerable<IHasUUID> indexBy) where T : IHasUUID
        {
            var indexer = GetIndexByKeys<T>(indexBy);
            var indexHash = GetHashKey(indexBy);

            return GetIndexValues<T>(indexer, indexHash);
        }
        private IEnumerable<T> GetIndexValues<T>(DataIndex dataIndex, string indexHash) where T : IHasUUID
        {
            if (dataIndex == null)
                return new List<T>();

            return dataIndex.Index[indexHash].ToList() as List<T>;
        }
}
```

However I am getting null back from `GetIndexValues`. I also tried returning it as an IEnumerable, also null

Here's my Add to index method

```
public void AddManyToIndex<T>(IEnumerable<IHasUUID> keys, IEnumerable<IHasUUID> newItems) where T : IHasUUID
{
    var index = GetIndexByKeys<T>(keys) ?? CreateIndex<T>(keys);

    string indexKey = GetHashKey(keys);

    if (!index.Index.ContainsKey(indexKey))
    {
        index.Index[indexKey] = new List<IHasUUID>();
    }

        var list = index.Index[indexKey].ToList();
        list.AddRange(newItems.ToList());
        index.Index[indexKey] = list as IEnumerable<IHasUUID>;
}
```

Comment: " An index has a name, and a List of objects" - consider using a different term than "index" to describe this, because "index" in C# specifically refers to use of the `[]` operator.

Comment: `GetIndexedItems` returns `List<IHasUUID>`, not `List<T>`, and the `List<T>` type (not the interface `IList<T>`) does not support generic type covariance.

Comment: What about `return indexedIds.Cast<T>().ToList();`? It requires running `Cast<>()` on each element, though. But how would you expect C# to know that a particular `IHasUUID` is a `T`? Just because a cat is a pet, it doesn't follow that a pet is a cat.

Comment: @Dai is correct. By the way, do you really need to take and return lists from these methods? IMO, this is bad API design. You could use `IReadOnlyList<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: @AluanHaddad sure I can use `IEnumerable` that's a good point! Even more so since I am considering using arrays so limiting to lists is a problem.

Comment: @JordanBrooklyn Arrays implement `IReadOnlyList<T>`.

Comment: @Dai Ah I did not realize that thank you.  I'm realizing I have a lot to learn to get this working.. heh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` is not [covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/). That is to say that, given two types `T` and `U` where a `U` is a `T`, a `List<U>` is **not** a `List<T>`.

This is why the cast fails, a list of a type implementing `IHasUUID`, `T` in your example, is **not** a `List<IHasUUID>`.

There are however, covariant<sup>**1**</sup> generic types, such as [`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=netcore-3.1) and [`System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlylist-1?view=netcore-3.1). For such types, given two types `T` and `U` where a `U` is a `T`, an `IEnumerable<U>` *is* an `IEnumerable<T>`.

In addition to solving your specific problem, using such types will also serve to make your APIs more flexible while at the same time making your implementation simpler and easier.

Consider the following:

```
public interface IHasUuid
{
    Guid Uuid { get; }
}

public class DataIndex
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<IHasUuid>> Index { get; } = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<IHasUuid>>();
}

public class Indexer
{
    public IEnumerable<IHasUuid> GetIndexedItems(IEnumerable<IHasUuid> indexBy)
    {
        var indexer = GetIndexByKeys<IHasUuid>(indexBy);
        var indexHash = GetHashKey(indexBy);

        return GetIndexValues<IHasUuid>(indexer, indexHash);
    }


    private IEnumerable<T> GetIndexValues<T>(DataIndex dataIndex, string hash) where T : IHasUuid
    {
        if (dataIndex == null)
            return Enumerable.Empty<T>();

        return dataIndex.Index[hash] as IEnumerable<T>;
    }
}
```

You can store any type that implements `IEnumerable<IHasUuid>` in `DataIndex.Index`. All generic collections in .NET implement this interface, including [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netcore-3.1), [`HashSet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netcore-3.1), [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netcore-3.1) and countless more.

If you wish to retain the defensive copying in the orginal code, which may well be wise, simply add the `.ToWhatever()` back to the code.

```
private IEnumerable<T> GetIndexValues<T>(DataIndex dataIndex, string hash) where T : IHasUuid
{
    if (dataIndex == null)
        return Enumerable.Empty<T>();

    return (dataIndex.Index[hash] as IEnumerable<T>).ToHashSet();
}
```

For example, you can build up a `DataIndex` instance like this

```
class Person: IHasUuid {
    public Guid Uuid { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
}

var index = new DataIndex {
    Index = {
        ["People"] = new List<Person>()
    }
};

var indexer = new Indexer();

var people = indexer.GetIndexValues(index, "People");
```

Here's a working fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qgjXR7

**1**: A type is covariant over its type parameter if that type parameter is declared using the [`out`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier) modifier. As its name suggests, the `out` modifier means that type parameter to which it is ascribed may only be used in output positions in the declaring type.

```
interface Wrapper<out T>
{
    T Value { get; } // OK

    T Value { get; set; } // Error

    void SetValue(T value); // Error
}
```

[Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-generic-interfaces) and [delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-delegates) types can declare covariant type parameters, concrete types such as classes and structs may not.

---

Comment: Ah thank you for such a detailed explanation! I don't seem to be able to actually return my data from GetIndexValues<T>

            ```dataIndex.Index[indexHash] as IEnumerable<T>;```

is null. The values are in the index before casting.

I tried casting it to my actual list, still null
            ```return dataIndex.Index[indexHash].ToList() as List<T>;```

The only thing that works is
            ```var data = dataIndex.Index[indexHash] as List<IHasUUID>;
            return data.Cast<T>().ToList();```

(Which is very slow) am I missing something?

Comment: I am storing an actual list in the dictionary (which is ```string, IEnumerable<IHasUUID>``` as you suggested)
            ```if (!index.Index.ContainsKey(indexKey))
            {
                index.Index[indexKey] = new List<IHasUUID>();
            }```

Comment: I'm dumb, the last example should be `return (dataIndex.Index[hash] as IEnumerable<T>).ToHashSet();` otherwise you get a HashSet<IHasUuid>`. Fixed example

Comment: By the way, you can use any generic collection you've a mind to. I was mixing it up to underscore the implementation flexibility gained by returning `IEnumerable<T>` by showing how the implementation could return a `HashSet<T>` without any changes to the caller.

Comment: Ahh yeah that did it, I didn't catch that either.  Thanks so much, things are working now, and I learned a lot in the process!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. That was my hope.